# Scroll and add Search Bar asynchronously

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, ipod

I have this application in which I have a right bar button item which adds the search bar as title view. This works fine but when the table view is scrolling, this doesn't happen. It only adds when the table view has stopped scrolling.

Any way to handle this?

Comment: This sounds like you are adding the search bar on the fly.  Is the user doing the scrolling or are you doing it programmatically?   The user interface changes to the best of my knowledge require the main thread and something (the scrolling) is blocking the main thread.  You need to give the UI a chance to make the change.

Comment: I need exactly how calendar app works. Both are running on main thread, that I know. Any idea to overcome this?

Comment: You need to "pause" your codes execution long enough for the UI to get some processing time on the main thread to make the UI update. generally if you make a call to change something in the UI it doesn't actually appear to the user (take effect) until your code relinquishes control of the main thread.    I would need to see more of your code to make a suggestion of how to adjust your code to allow that change to appear to the user.

Comment: Well I solved the problem by setting the contentOffset of TableView. This stops the scrolling and main thread gets free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thread does not responds to events if its busy, use GCD to add this to Queue

Check if this function is called while scrolling. If yes , then simply using GCD will solve your problem.

```
-(void)userTapOnRightBarButton{
    NSLog(@"Main thread response to touch during scrolling"):
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self addSearchBar];
   });
}
```